# C# Retrieving transitive data from database

Tags: c#, sql-server

relatively new programmer here attempting to tackle a task that may be slightly over my head.

I'm attempting to create a method that will return all transitive relationships for an item. To be specific, I have a simple table that contains items that may be directly or indirectly related to one another:

```
ID | Item# | RelativeItem#
--------------------------
0  | Item1 | Item2
1  | Item2 | Item3
2  | Item4 | Item1
3  | Item5 | Item6
4  | Item7 | Item8
5  | Item8 | Item9
6  | Item10| Item6
7  | Item12| Item11
```

Example 1: Searching Item1 should return Item2(directly related),Item3(indirectly related), and Item4(indirectly related)

Example 2: Searching Item10 should return Item5, Item6, Item7. Item8, and Item9

Example 3: Searching Item11 should return Item12

My original thought was to utilize a recursive CTE and return the results but I soon realized that not only is there not a way to translate that into a Linq query but it also wouldn't be ideal to run such a query each time an item needs to be searched. What are some options to efficiently query the table and retrieve relative items?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. Your sample output doesn't make sense based on the data provided. This sounds like a typical recursive cte to me.

Answer (score 0):

A recursive CTE is the most efficient option.  You can put it in a VIEW if you need to query it via linq.